What happens if I use an LTO cleaning tape after 50 uses
I would like to know what would happen if one keeps using an LTO cleaning tape for more than 50 times (limit recommended by manufacturers).
If cleaning tapes are scarce or unavailable, how further can such limit be pushed, and what are the consequences?
Edit:
In particular, what would happen if the LTO drive is part of an automatic LTO tape library

I'm not sure whether the limit is just a recommendation or a hard limit (enforced by the cartridge memory). Most likely, the cleaning cycle is skipped and the tape ejected.

Duplicate with Determining LTO Cleaning Tape Expiration? ??


what are the consequences?

Purchase a new tape drive is one consequence.

Could you provide more detail? How exactly does a heavily used cleaning tape damage the drive? (ineffective cleaning => remaining debris messes things up maybe?)

More details: neglect may result in failure.
